# Select a post that does not have a particular tag

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, subquery

I have a post/tag database, with the usual post, tag, and tag_post tables. The tag_post table contains tagid and postid fields.

I need to query posts. When I want to fetch posts that have a certain tag, I have to use a join:

```
... INNER JOIN tag_post ON post.id = tag_post.postid 
WHERE tag_post.tagid = {required_tagid}`
```

When I want to fetch posts that have tagIdA and tagIdB, I have to use two joins (which I kind of came to terms with eventually).

Now, I need to query posts that do not have a certain tag. Without much thought, I just changed the `=` to `!=`:

```
... INNER JOIN tag_post ON post.id = tag_post.postid 
WHERE tag_post.tagid != {certain_tagid}`
```

Boom! Wrong logic!

I did come up with this - just writing the logic here:

```
... INNER JOIN tag_post ON post.id = tag_post.postid 
WHERE tag_post.postid NOT IN 
(SELECT postid from tag_post where tagid = {certain_tagid})
```

I know this will work, but due to the way I've been brought up, I feel guilty (justified or not) whenever I write a query with a subquery.

Suggest a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of it as "find all rows in posts that do not have a match in tags (for a specific tag)"

This is the textbook use case for a LEFT JOIN.

```
LEFT JOIN tag_post ON post.id = tag_post.postid AND tag_post.tagid = {required_tagid}
WHERE tag_post.tag_id IS NULL
```

Note that you have to have the tag id in the ON clause of the join.

For a reference on join types, see here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Thanks - your reply also makes clear the difference between ON and WHERE clause - which can be used interchangeably in INNER joins. The link is great too!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Gavin Towey's good answer, you can use a `not exists` subquery:

```
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    tag_post
        where   post.id = tag_post.postid
                and tag_post.tagid = {required_tagid}
        )
```

The database typically executes both variants in the same way.  I personally find the `not exists` approach easier to read.

Comment: @Quassnoi wrote a [blog article](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) on anti-join patterns in MySQL and concluded that `EXISTS` is 30% less efficient than the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

1. > When I want to fetch posts that have tagIdA and tagIdB, I have to use two joins (which I kind of came to terms with eventually).

   There are other ways.

   One can obtain all the `id` of all posts that are tagged with both `tagid` 123 and 456 by grouping filtering `tag_post` for only those tags, grouping by post and then dropping any groups that contain fewer tags than expected; then one can use the result to filter the `posts` table:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id IN (
     SELECT   postid
     FROM     tag_post
     WHERE    tagid IN (123,456)
     GROUP BY postid
     HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
   )
   ```

   If a post can be tagged with the same `tagid` multiple times, you will need to replace `COUNT(*)` with the less performant `COUNT(DISTINCT tagid)`.
2. > Now, I need to query posts that do not have a certain tag.

   This is known as an anti-join.  The easiest way is to replace `IN` from the query above with `NOT IN`, as you proposed.  I wouldn't feel too guilty about it.  The alternative is to use an outer join, as proposed in [@GavinTowey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12439837/623041).

Comment: Nice. But the subquery guilt kicks in. However I think after a certain number of ANDs, this will become more effecient than multiple joins.

Comment: @merlinbeard: You could alternatively form joins with the table materialised from the subquery (inner and outer joins for cases 1 and 2 above, respectively); it results in an equivalent execution plan, so is purely a cosmetic change.  I find this approach is more readable.  As you say, when one is searching for multiple tags the no-subquery approach requires scanning (and then joining) `tag_post` multiple times, which is almost certainly less efficient.

Comment: @eggyal -- there's a far better way to do #1 that lets you use the same join:  SELECT * FROM posts JOIN tag_post ON ... WHERE tagid IN (123,456) GROUP BY postid HAVING SUM(tagid=123) AND SUM(tagid=456)

Comment: @GavinTowey: Ooooh, I like that!  :)