# mysql - select posts all that are not tagged hidden

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

So I have three tables, one is `posts` , having columns `id,title,content,timestamp` . Other is `tags`, having columns `id,tag` and third `posttags` describes one to many relation between `posts` and `tags` , having columns `postid,tagid` .

Now instead of having columns like `hidden,featured` etc in the table `posts` to describe whether a post should be visible to all or should be displayed on a special *featured* page, I thought why not use tags to save time. So what I decided is that all posts that have a tag `#featured` will be featured and all posts with tag `#hidden` will be hidden.

Implementing first one was easy as I could use a join query and in my where clause I could mention `WHERE tag='featured'` and this would get all the featured posts for me.

But take an example of a post tagged `#sports` and `#hidden` if I were to use the query

```
SELECT * FROM posts
INNER JOIN posttags ON posttags.postid = posts.id
INNER JOIN tags ON posttags.tagid = tags.id
WHERE tag !='hidden'
```

but that'd still return the post tagged `hidden` since its also tagged `sports`

**PS** my question is different from this question : [Select a post that does not have a particular tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439820/select-a-post-that-does-not-have-a-particular-tag) since it uses tagid directly and I'm unable to achieve same result using double join to check against tag name instead of tagid. And also I wish to retrieve the other tags of the post in same query which is not possible using the method in that question's answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `NOT EXISTS` subquery:

```
SELECT p.*, t.*                          -- what columns you need
FROM posts AS p
  INNER JOIN posttags AS pt
    ON pt.postid = p.id
  INNER JOIN tags AS t
    ON pt.tagid = t.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM posttags AS pt_no
          INNER JOIN tags AS t_no
            ON pt_no.tagid = t_no.id
        WHERE t_no.tag = 'hidden'
          AND pt_no.postid = p.id
      ) ;
```

or the equivalent `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`:

```
SELECT p.*, t.* 
FROM posts AS p
  LEFT JOIN posttags AS pt_no
      INNER JOIN tags AS t_no
        ON  t_no.tag = 'hidden'
        AND pt_no.tagid = t_no.id
    ON pt_no.postid = p.id
  INNER JOIN posttags AS pt
    ON pt.postid = p.id
  INNER JOIN tags AS t
    ON pt.tagid = t.id
WHERE pt_no.postid IS NULL ;
```

Thsi type of queries are called anti-semijoins or just anti-joins. It's slightly more complex in your case because the condition (`tag='hidden'`) is in a 3rd table.

Comment: It's fast, but I'm not exactly sure how it works, what changes would I have to make to the query to retrieve the tags as well?

Comment: If you want all the tags of the posts, you can add another join.

Comment: unable to do it. could you post the whole query for getting all tags aswell?

Comment: there is some glitch in left join / is null equivalent, mysql says : #1054 - Unknown column 'pt.postid' in 'on clause' . 1st one is really fast!

Answer (score 4):

Group the tags by post, then use the `HAVING` clause to filter the groups for those that do not contain a `'hidden'` tag.  Because of MySQL's implicit type conversion and lack of genuine boolean types, one can do:

```
SELECT   posts.*
FROM     posts
    JOIN posttags ON posttags.postid = posts.id
    JOIN tags     ON posttags.tagid  = tags.id
GROUP BY posts.id
HAVING   NOT SUM(tag='hidden')
```

Comment: elegant and fast. Do you think I could also get the tags for the posts not tagged hidden in the same query without having to use a sub-query?

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha: If you're happy to obtain the tags as a delimited string you can add `GROUP_CONCAT(tag)` to the select list; otherwise you would have to join your `posttags` and `tags` tables back to the above result (using a subquery).

Comment: although your answer makes more sense to a mysql noob like me, ypercube's solution is faster and so I accepted that.